# TinyMCe installation problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I have installed tinymce at this location : http://adsane.net/editor/ But as you can see I am sure - it doesnt look right.

The JS console shows an error:`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
at line 8 which is :

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea" ---THIS LINE HERE
});
```

The HTML I am using is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tiny Mce</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure what is wrong - can somebody help?

Comment: Using the online link seems to work properly http://jsfiddle.net/9LKtJ/1

Answer (score 0):

try putting tinymce code inside:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
```

Comment: Same problem makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, because I copy pasted the code snippet there was unidentifiably characters in the markup :/ - starting a new file and retyping works fine :)